# Building AST in OCaml

Tags: parsing, ocaml, grammar

I'm using OCaml to build a recursive descent parser for a subset of Scheme. Here's the grammar:

```
    S -> a|b|c|(T)
    T -> ST | Epsilon
```

So say I have:

```
   type expr = 
       Num of int | String of string | Tuple of expr * expr
```

**Pseudocode**

These functions have to return expr type to build the AST

```
parseS  lr =
   if head matches '(' then
     parseL lr
   else
     match tokens a, b, or c
```

Using First Set of S which are tokens and '(':

```
parseL lr = 
   if head matches '(' or the tokens then
       Tuple (parseS lr, parseL lr)
  else
       match Epsilon
```

My question is "How do I return for the Epsilon part since I just can't return ()?". An OCaml function requires same return type and even if I leave blank for Epsilon part, OCaml still assumes unit type.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As far as I can see, your AST doesn't match your grammar.

You can solve the problem by having a specifically empty node in your AST type to represent the Epsilon in your grammar.

Or, you can change your grammar to factor out the Epsilon.

Here's an equivalent grammar with no Epsilon:

```
S -> a|b|c|()|(T)
T -> S | S T
```

Comment: so to my understanding, either I have to include a place holder for Epsilon or adjust the given grammar as you mentioned. That seems to eliminate the Epsilon problem. Does that mean whenever I see Epsilon, I have rewrite the grammar?

Comment: I would say yes, in concept. In practice it just means you look ahead in your parser. If you're writing the parser by hand you can probably make it work without spending a lot of time rewriting the grammar.

Comment: If S returns a, b, c of type expr, what should I return for () part in S?

Comment: I'd say you want to use a list to represent your tuple. Then use an empty list for `()`. This is what I meant when I said your AST type doesn't really match your grammar.

Comment: oh, that makes sense. I was restricting myself to think in terms of tuple. Thank you. :)

Comment: Actually, I came up with another problem. Now in `T -> S | ST`, how would I know which branch to take since they both have same First Sets? If I try to left factor it with another level, I would go back to the Epsilon problem. Or am I understanding it wrong?

Comment: You're writing the code yourself--you can always parse an S and then see what shows up after that.

Comment: Thank you for being patient.

Answer (score 4):

Maybe instead of creating parser-functions manually it is better to use existent approaches: for example, LALR(1) [ocamlyacc](http://plus.kaist.ac.kr/~shoh/ocaml/ocamllex-ocamlyacc/ocamlyacc-tutorial/) or camlp4 based LL(k) [parsers](http://www.ffconsultancy.com/ocaml/benefits/parsing.html) ?

Comment: Thanks guys :). But I can't use existing utilities since this is an exercise.